# Creating list angled at 45 degrees and aligned to bottom either with css or jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, transform

I am trying to create a ul list of text angled at -45 degrees which also needs to be aligned to the bottom and neatly spaced (well so I can control the spacing nicely).

Like the elements at the top of [this page](http://www.grasshopperwaiheke.co.nz/Waiheke_Bus_Timetable_files/Bus%20timetable%20-%20Onetangi.jpg)

HTML:

```
 <div class="route-diagram">
        <ul class="routes">
            <li class="first">Pennywell, Quarry View</li>
            <li>Pallion, Forfield Road</li>
            <li>Royal Hospital, Hylton Road</li>
            <li>Millfield Metro</li>
            <li>Sunderland, Green Terrace</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
            <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        </ul>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .route-diagram ul.routes {
list-style:none;
 }

.route-diagram ul.routes li {
display:inline;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
/*
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
*/
zoom:1;
 }
```

I have started a jsfiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/3SFE2/)

My question is would this be easier to control in separate divs (it seems a list is alot cleaner and easier to maintain). Alternatively would a jquery plugin give me more options?

I am worried about spacing the list nicely it seems to be very awkward in my html and as shown in the fiddle.

If anyone can help with this or has some good advice I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a nice jquery function to incrementally add the margin left:

```
 var $addMargin = 0;
 var $listItems = $('ul.routes li');
     $listItems.each(function(){
         $addMargin += 25;
         $(this).css('margin-left', $addMargin + 'px');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rotating each element, I rotated the whole list, which required adding quite a bit of redundant CSS syntax like:

```
.elemX { margin-left: Ypx; }
```

Still requires some polishing, yet it seems to work as you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/GHWcZ/

Comment: I cant see any difference between that fiddle and my own. Did you make an update to the code? i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/GHWcZ/1

Comment: Thanks. Whilst I am not against this method it does require individual styling to each element, which is more expensive than styling the ul and li elements.